# Is there an way in cypress to assert a new tab opening without target or remove attribute as i have href as something like this?

Tags: javascript, testing, cucumber, cypress, gherkin

I have the element something like this and i am writing the code something like this to click

```
Then('I click on the Help Icon > {string}', (option) => {
    cy.get('.icon-help').click({ force: true })
    cy.get('ul a')
        .contains(option)
        .click({ force: true })
});
```

as i need to click first and
assert that the page is opening in the next step but the page is opening in a new tab and to remove attribute or _target there is no target attribute.Its completely opening in new tab so how i can assert that the page opening in new tab?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no href, it might be that there's a click handler that calls `window.open`.

If so, stub the call and assert it was called.

```js
cy.get('.icon-help').click({ force: true })

cy.window().then(win => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open').as('open')
})
cy.get('ul a').contains(option).click({ force: true })
cy.get('@open').should('have.been.called')
```